# Loading svg in preact with vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, preact

I wonder how can I load svg`s in preact & vite for now I have tried simple import

```
import SvgLogo from './test.svg'

export const Logo = () => (
    <SvgLogo />
)
```

but I doesnt render anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Universal solution for multiple images.
Two files:

1. assets.js
2. main.js

assets.js :

```
export { default as prelogo } from '../assets/images/prelogo.png';

export { default as logo } from '../assets/images/logo.png';
```

main.js :

```
import * as assets from '../assets';
```

...

```
<div>
<img src={assets.prelogo}  alt="" />
<img src={assets.logo}  alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the img tag:

```
import SvgLogo from './test.svg'

export const Logo = () => (
    <img src={SvgLogo} />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render image with any kind of extension whether it is SVG or PNG or JPG by Importing the image, you need to use the `<img/>` tag.

change the code to,

```
import SvgLogo from './test.svg'

export const Logo = () => (
    <img src={SvgLogo}/>
)
```

it should do the work